# C function passes function as a parameter, How to wrap this function using node-ffi?

Tags: c, node.js, ffi, node-ffi

I am trying to wrap c code using node-ffi. But one c function calls a function in a parameter, I searched on the web but I didn't get any proper way to wrap the same function using node-ffi.

Here is what I tried before(snippet),

example.js

```
var intPin = 40;
var state = 0;
var lib = require('./c_functions');
lib.c_functions.attachInterrupt(intPin,abc); //attachInterrupt is a c function and **Problem 1**

function abc(){
    console.log("state: ",state);
    state++;
}
```

c_functions.js //file accesses library and exports functions

```
var ffi = require('ffi');     //requires to use node-ffi functionalities
var ref = require('ref');     //reference to integer type
var int = ref.types.int;
var voidtype = ref.types.void;
var objPtr = ref.refType(voidType);  //void pointer

var c_functions = ffi.Library('/usr/local/lib/lib.so.0.5.0', {  //accessing so file
    "attachInterrupt":[voidtype, [int,objPtr]] // **Problem 2**
});
/**
 *  @breif Definitions for Pin modes
 */
var INPUT = 0;
var OUTPUT = 1;
/**
 *  @breif Definitions for pin values
 */

var LOW = 0;
var HIGH = 1;

module.exports = {c_functions , HIGH, LOW, INPUT, OUTPUT}; //exporting functions
```

So I am having 2 problems,

**1. Problem 2(In code) -** What should be the type of 2nd argument of attachInterrupt function ?

**2. Problem 1(In code) -** How to call the function which is passed as a parameter ?

Please help ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [ffi.Callback()](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial) which basically returns a pointer that can be passed to a C function:
solution for your problem would look like something like this (example.js):

```
const intPin = 40;
const state = 0;
const lib = require('./c_functions');

const abc = () => {
    console.log("state: ",state);
    state++;
}

const pointerToMyFunction = ffi.Callback('void', [], abc);

//now pass pointer of abc() to attachInterrupt function
lib.c_functions.attachInterrupt(intPin,pointerToMyFunction);
```

`ffi.Callback` accepts return type, argument types and javascript function as parameters and return pointer to this function. I passed empty array as second parameter because `abc()` doesn't accept anything. you can see more examples in the link above.

(also try to use `const` and `let` instead of `var` :d)

Comment: Hi @rezga, Thank you so much for your answer, actually I moved on to the next task, so after this task I will come back to this and check.